# Show keyboard on android device using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard

I have a web page which has many input text fields.
When I tap on the first field that I want to enter data into the keyboard is displayed just fine.
After updating the field I tap the 'Next' key on the keyboard and the cursor moves to the next input field as desired, the keyboard however disappears and I have to touch the input field that now has focus to make it show again.
Can I prevent the keyboard from hiding when the 'Next' key is tapped or is there any way to make the keyboard using JavaScript using the onFocus event?

Just so you have all of the information you need:
All text boxes have an onchange javascript function to validate the data and the fields are defined thus:

```
<input class='Order-Quantity' type='number' maxlength='3' pattern='[0-9]{3}' name='txtQuantityInput' onChange='javascript:CheckQuantity(this)' />
```

I have tried adding a setTimeout delay and manually focusing on the new element but this did not achieve the desired affect.

Any help much appreciated.
Nibbo